# Not able to find esapi-3.1.0.jar

Tags: esapi

downloaded a book from the below link

https://www.owasp.org/images/7/79/ESAPI_Book.pdf

The book is depended on the esapi-3.10 version. But i am not able to find esapi-3.1.0.jar.
Where can find the respective jar.

Thank you.
~Shyam

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it probably was a typo, but more likely it was supposed to say ESAPI 1.3 rather than 3.1. That's even about a year before I got involved with ESAPI. If you notice the date for this was 2008 and I just checked and release 1.3 was made available in Sept 2008.

So, in other words, this ESAPI book is really ancient history. And the previous answer is correct in that the latest official release is 2.1.0. The 2.1.1 release is almost done but because of other commitments (e.g., GSoC), it will likely be awhile until it is released unless I get some volunteers to assist.

-kevin

Answer (score 0):

Notify OWASP.  The most recent version of esapi is 2.1.0.  This is a typo.